# Is it ok to use an inner tube that is slightly too large for the tire?

Tags: innertube

My hybrid bike tire measurement says 700x35c. I ordered a replacement inner tube stating it was 700x35-40c but when it arrived it is actually 700x38-45c. Could I still use this or will it cause a problem, e.g. with my brakes?

Comment: Any larger and I would worry, but that much of a mismatch isn't likely to be a problem.  I would be suspicious of your supplier, though, if they can't supply the right sized tube.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Complete beginner's question: inner tube too big?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/15204/complete-beginners-question-inner-tube-too-big)

Comment: You're only slightly over the speced size but to be extra cautious you might dust the tube with cornstarch to keep it from sticky-binding to the tire, and after installed pump it up about 3/4 the way up, then deflate it, then pump it up to full desired pressure - you want to work out any kinks and folds from the tube.

Answer (score 9):

It won't cause a problem with your brakes – the tire casing will prevent the tube from "over expanding."

Your tire is a bit smaller than the small end of the range for the tube. You may find it a little harder to fit in the extra material and it would be good to take a bit of extra care to make sure you don't pinch the tube if you use tire levers.

Be careful to avoid any twists, but it should work. This question, *[Using a wider inner tube](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/15204/complete-beginners-question-inner-tube-too-big?rq=1)*, explains in more detail what can go wrong if the tube is significantly too large, and also points out that inflating the tube *slightly* will ease installation – especially in a case like this.